# How to prevent other websites from sending post data to my site in PHP

Tags: php

What is the best method to stop other websites from sending data to my website in PHP?

I googled it and found I need to use Hash. But there are different Hashes, which one to use? Let's say, I pick `sha1`

Now, how exactly can I prevent other websites from sending post data to my website with `sha1`

I am bit confused, can someone show me a little demo code.

This is the code, I thought, but it is not flawless..

`Index.php page:`

```
$password = sha1("toby123");

<form method="post" action="insert.php" />
<input type="text" name="username"/>
<input type="password" name="password"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenpass" value=" ".$password." "/>
</form>
```

Insert Into Database PHP Page:

```
$hiddenpass = "toby123" 

if (  $_POST["hiddenpass"] == "sha1($hiddenpass )"  )

{
// INSERT THE DATA
}
```

But the problem here is, `hash` code in the form will be visiable to everyone. What if someone crack it?

I mean, by using a Hit & Trial method???

Is my method 100% safe??

**Edit:**

This is my new code after looking at one of the answer, but the If condition is always false.

Index.php Page

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();


    $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    }

?>
```

Insert.php Page:

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['token'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $_POST['token'];

if (  ( isset($_SESSION['token']) )  &&  ( $_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token'] ) )

{

// Insert Data

}
else
echo "<br/>Something went wrong";


unset($_SESSION['token']);
```

**Output:**

> 055442be59701631db6ed88dc341027ebf2238507bb9a72f1caefd6d3b126a4b
>
> 055442be59701631db6ed88dc341027ebf2238507bb9a72f1caefd6d3b126a4b
>
> Something went wrong

Comment: You can't stop them from sending POST data this way (by the time PHP runs the request has already been sent), but the term you should be looking for is CSRF tokens which are throw away one off tokens.

Comment: @JonStirling this comment should be an answer

Comment: Unsure. It's less of an answer and more a "you should go research this term", which isn't strictly an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be securing your forms by adding using CSRF tokens. The CSRF token should always be random. CSRF stands for **(Cross Site Request Frogery)**

---

**Here is a good and secure method:**

```
<?php

function random_token()
{

    $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));

    return $token;
}


function gentoken()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $_SESSION['token'] = random_token();
    }
}


function checktoken($token)
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && $token === $_SESSION['token']) {
        deletetoken();
        return true;
    }
    return false; // default
}


function deletetoken()
{
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

?>
```

**And here should be your form**

```
<form method="post" action="insert.php"/>
<input type="text" name="username"/>
<input type="password" name="password"/>
<input type = "hidden" name="token" value="' . $_SESSION['token'] . '">
<input type = "submit" name="submit" value="Insert"/>
</form>
```

**When the page starts, write this:**

```
gentoken();

**And to check for the token do this**



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $token = $_POST['token'];
    if (checktoken($token)) {

    } else {
        echo "Something wrong happened"; //When the token is changed or doesn't match!
    }

}
```

---

**Notes:**

`random_bytes()` generates secure cryptographical bytes and doesn't need to be hashed!

I hope this helped. Good luck!

Comment: I never used function in PHP. But i think this code can be down without functions also, right? So why use functions? Why complicate the code.

Comment: @Toby I normally make a file called functions.php with code that I use for more than 1 page, and whenever I need to use it back, I just include the functions file in the other page, instead of writing it over and over every time!

Comment: Hey idk why, but this condition `    if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && $token === $_SESSION['token']) {` is always false...

Comment: I echo'ed $_SESSION['token'] and $token, both are same..but it is always false..what is the problem?

Comment: @Toby Have you started your session? Start it by using session_start(); And if it didn't work edit your post with the full code you use in both of your files so I can help you!

Comment: Inside your insert.php start the session also and after else put these { } and then edit the post with your new code ( Including the form )

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using "toby123" use much cmplex and long random generated string.
 For more security you can use two hashes.

```
session_start();
// if there is data submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$password1 = $_SESSION['password1'];
$password2 = $_SESSION['password2'];
//check these passwords
if($_POST['password1']==$password1 && $_POST['password2']==$password2){
// code to pe processed

}else{
echo '<h1>FORBIDDEN</h1>';
}
}else{
 $rand1 = md5(uniqid().mt_rand());
$rand1 = md5(uniqid().mt_rand().uniqid());
$password1 = sha1($rand1);
$password2 = sha1($rand2);
$_SESSION['password1'] = $password1;
$_SESSION['password2'] = $password2;
}
```

Comment: Not secure: mt_rand is no longer secure, It doesn't even generate secure cryptographical bytes and is able to be cracked and predicted by brute force!